# When using tkinter in Python 3, how do you get a button to run a function each time it is pressed?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
import tkinter as tk
panel = tk.Tk()
num = 42
lbl1 = tk.Label(panel, text = str(num))
```

Let's say I have a function and button like this:

```
def increase():
    lbl1.configure(text = str(num+1))

btn = tk.Button(panel, text = 'Increase', command = increase)

panel.mainloop()
```

This button will make the number that is the label increase by 1 when pressing the button. However, this only works once before the button does absolutely nothing. How can I make it so that every time I press the button, the number increases by 1?

Answer (score 2):

You never saved the incremented value of `num`.

```
def increase():
    global num # declare it a global so we can modify it
    num += 1 # modify it
    lbl1.configure(text = str(num)) # use it
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because num is always 43

```
import tkinter as tk
num = 42

def increase():
    global num
    num += 1
    lbl1.configure(text = str(num))


panel = tk.Tk()

lbl1 = tk.Label(panel, text = str(num))
lbl1.pack()
btn = tk.Button(panel, text = 'Increase', command = increase)
btn.pack()
panel.mainloop()
```